# A line graph instead of histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

hi there I hope you all doing great

I have created this graph as a boxplot

[My boxplot graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cioz7.png)

by this code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)
library(skimr)
library(janitor)
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
library(readr)
library(scales)
library(flextable)
library(gtsummary)
library(magrittr)
library(parameters)
library(ggplot2)
library(haven)
library(ggsignif)
library(reshape2)
library(ggpubr)

R_v2 <- read_csv("R_v2.csv")
PE <- clean_names(R_v2) 

colnames(PE) <- c("Risk_Group", "TKV(0.6_rpm)", "TKV(0.8_rpm)", "TKV(1_rpm)")

PE1 <- setDT(copy(PE))


PE_plot5 <- melt(PE1, 
                 measure.vars = c("TKV(0.6_rpm)", "TKV(0.8_rpm)", "TKV(1_rpm)"),
                 value.name = "TKV_viscosity",  variable.name = "TKV")


ggplot(PE_plot5, aes(x = TKV, y = TKV_viscosity)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.7, alpha = 0.8, aes(fill = as.factor(Risk_Group))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4271AE", "#FF5A5F"), labels = c("Low Risk", "High Risk")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "grey20", size = 12, vjust = 0.4),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  base_breaks_y(PE_plot5$TKV_viscosity, name = "Viscosity (cP)", 
                labels = label_number(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  base_breaks_x_discrete(PE_plot5$TKV, name = "Shear rate (1/s)", 
                         labels = c("0.6 RPM", "0.8 RPM", "1.0 RPM"))
```

But now I need to make it a line graph like this

[The graph type I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uwnG.png)

Here is reproducible data
(I couldn't upload a csf file I hope this can work by copy paste)

| Risk Group | TKV (0.6) | TKV (0.8) | TKV (1) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7.5 | 7.3 | 7.1 |
| 0 | 6.8 | 6.6 | 6.4 |
| 0 | 7.3 | 7.1 | 6.9 |
| 0 | 7.1 | 6.9 | 6.7 |
| 0 | 7.4 | 7.2 | 7.0 |
| 1 | 7.8 | 7.6 | 7.4 |
| 1 | 7.1 | 6.9 | 6.7 |
| 1 | 7.6 | 7.4 | 7.2 |
| 1 | 7.4 | 7.2 | 7.0 |
| 1 | 7.7 | 7.5 | 7.3 |

I've made this one

```
ggplot(PE_plot5, aes(x = TKV, y = TKV_viscosity, group = Risk_Group, color = as.factor(Risk_Group))) +
  geom_smooth(size = 3) +
  geom_path(size = 1.5, alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#4271AE", "#FF5A5F"), labels = c("Low Risk", "High Risk")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "grey20", size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "grey20", size = 12, vjust = 0.4),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "Shear rate (1/s)", y = "Viscosity (cP)") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("0.6 RPM", "0.8 RPM", "1.0 RPM"))
```

but it's ugly as you can see here
(also I don't want a verticle line at each x-axis a circle would be fine)

[Close but not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWoL8.png)

Comment: Sure, share your data in a reproducible format we can copy / paste into our console and we can help you with that

Comment: FYI, your initial chart is a boxplot and not a histogram.  While  not important for the question it helps by getting the terminology correct.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. object PE_plot5 not found. Here is what you should do: REMOVE all variables from your environment. RERUN the code. make sure it runs. COPY it. PASTE it here. If its anything other than a code we can run ourselves >> IT IS NOT REPRODUCIBLE.

Comment: thank you  @Dave2e 
I'm sorry for that, I asked that question 3'Am so that might be the problem 
thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)    
df <- tibble(risk = sample(c(0,1),10,TRUE),
                 TKV6 = sample(runif(100),10),
                 TKV8 = sample(runif(100),10),
                 TKV1 = sample(runif(100),10)) |> round(2) |> 
      mutate(risk = as.factor(risk))
    
    df |> ggplot(aes(TKV6,TKV8,shape=risk,color=risk,group=1))+geom_line()+
      geom_point()+
      scale_color_manual(values = c("lightgreen","lightpink"))+ # choose your desired colors
      scale_shape_manual(values = c(4,7))+ # choose your desired shapes
      labs(x="",y="",shape="",color="")+
      theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            legend.position = c(.9,0.8),
            legend.direction = "horizontal",
            text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Is it close to what you wanted? your code is not reproducible so i kinda guessed.
[image]

Comment: thank you very much @RYann 

but I wanted the TKV 0.6 TKV 0.8 TKV 1 as the x-axis 

so it shows the mean of TKV0.6 for the 0 risk group and 1 risk group 
connected with a line to TKV 0.8 that connected to TKV 1 

I've edited the post so it should be reproducible now